# Determine cells in a formula in Excel 2007

Tags: c#, vba, excel, vsto

I am writing an application which aims to protect the cells involved / referenced in a formula.
e.g.

if cell A1 contains a formula that sums 2 cells as = B1 + C1,

The use case is : when user accidentally attempts to change contents of cell B1, C1 then application  notifies user that such an operation is not allowed hence resets the contents.

I am able to reset the contents of individual cells but my concern is to find cells involved in a formula first.

is there a way out that knowing there is a formula in a cell, I can find cells involved in it?
Any sort of help is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Keywords: `HasFormula` and `Precedents`

Comment: It might come from other sheets too.

Comment: @Shaktisaxena to trace off-sheet precedents (as per your post above) you need to use `NavigateArrows`. The accepted answer from Mehow will only give local sheet references

Comment: so do u have any sample code for that??

Comment: @Shaktisaxena as an example see http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?19348-Solved-Splitting-all-addresses-in-a-formula&s=6cf3444bebea1ebbeeea52860ce7087f&p=142863#post142863

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923684/how-do-you-test-that-a-range-in-excel-has-cells-in-it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the below Macro in a **new workbook**. It will show you precedents of cell B1

`B1` has a formula `=SUM(A1,A3,A5,A7,A9,A10)`

and the msgbox should tell you exactly which cells are used in the formula.

```
Sub Main()

    Range("A1").Resize(10, 1).Formula = "=Rand()"

    Range("B1").Formula = "=SUM(A1,A3,A5,A7,A9,A10)"


    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Range("B1")
        If cell.HasFormula Then
            MsgBox cell.Precedents.Address
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Well, I have not tried this. But my curiosity is that does it also show cells between A1:A9???

Comment: well, you should try :) this will show you only `A1,A3,A5,A7,A9,A10`, but if the formula was `SUM(A1:A10)` it would show you `A1:A10` so based on the separator you can tell which cells exactly are used. Ie. `For each cell in Range(Range("B1").Precedents.Address) msgbox cell.address next`